# 2 identic functions do something different

Tags: php, sql

Im doing two queries to a database, they are functional the same, but with other values.

**CODE1 :**

```
$sql= "SELECT sum(amount) as Samount, sum(add25) as Sadd25, sum(add50) as Sadd50, sum(deplacement) as Sdeplacement FROM workhours WHERE reportID = '$reportID'";
$sumWorkhoursData=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
unset($sql);
while($sWorhoursInfo=mysqli_fetch_array($sumWorkhoursData)){
$totalWork = $sumWorkhoursInfo['Samount'];
print_r(var_dump($sWorkhoursInfo));
}
```

the var_dump gives `NULL`
If the `$sql` is copied to database manually, then it gets a good result which is one row.

**CODE2 :**

```
$sql= "select sum(time) as Stime, sum(amount) as Samount FROM trip WHERE reportID = '$reportID'";
$sumTripData=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
unset($sql);
while ($sTripInfo=mysqli_fetch_array($sumTripData)){
$totalTrip = $sTripInfo['Stime'];
print_r(var_dump($sTripInfo));
}
```

in this case, var_dump gives `array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "20" ["Stime"]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(3) "151" ["Samount"]=> string(3) "151" }`

what is wrong here?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: `Undefined variable: sWorkhoursInfo in /volume1/web/printx.php on line 35`.... but i knew this before,because var_dump is null, the question is why its undefined, the query works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a typo `$sWorhoursInfo` in `while($sWorhoursInfo` where it should be `$sWorkhoursInfo` missing the `k`

```
while($sWorkhoursInfo...
```

Comment: yes i did, sadly, it does not work when i fix it, still `$sumWorkhoursData` is nod defined...

Comment: aaaaaaah :S there is another typo :( i fixed it... i accept your answer :)

Comment: @hesamesa0r `$sumWorkhoursInfo` should have been `$sumWorkhoursData` correct?